# Defining percentage for random number

Tags: php

My `rand(0,1)` php function returns me the `0` and `1` randomly when I call it.

Can I define something in php, so that it makes `30%` numbers will be `0` and `70%` numbers will be `1` for the random calls? Does php have any built in function for this?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: agreed, but he wants a weighted random number generation. His question seems valid for certain use cases..

Comment: `$options = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]; echo $options[array_rand($options)]`?

Comment: `$rand = (rand(1,100) <= 70 ? 1 : 0)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure.

```
 $rand = (float)rand()/(float)getrandmax();
 if ($rand < 0.3)
    $result = 0;
 else
    $result = 1;
```

You can deal with arbitrary results and weights, too.

```
 $weights = array(0 => 0.3, 1 => 0.2, 2 => 0.5);
 $rand = (float)rand()/(float)getrandmax();
 foreach ($weights as $value => $weight) {
    if ($rand < $weight) {
       $result = $value;
       break;
    }
    $rand -= $weight;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, is there a reason to why you have used division operator here `$rand = (float)rand()/(float)getrandmax();` ? Thank you!

Comment: Because the return value of rand() is an integer between 0 and whatever `getrandmax()` is; by dividing the returned value by that maximum, I get a floating-point result between 0 and 1, which maps more easily to OP's desired percentages.

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like this:

```
$rand = (rand(0,9) > 6 ? 1 : 0)
```

`rand(0,9)` will produce a random number between 0 and 9, and whenever that randomly generated number is greater than 6 (which should be nearly 70% time), it will give you `1` otherwise `0`...

Obviously, it seems to be the easiest solution to me, but definitely, it wont give you `1` exactly 70% times, but should be quite near to do that, if done correctly.

*But, I doubt that any solution based on `rand` will give you `1` exactly 70% times...*

Comment: This one is very easy to use. But sometimes it can come up with 70% of 0 as well.

Comment: @sabujhassan: as I said, no other solution based on `rand` can ensure that this worst case scenario won't happen, `imho`, unless I'm wrong.

Comment: Isn't your logic backwards? 70% of the time it will produce `0`. Plus if you want more accuracy: `$rand = (rand(1,100) <= 70 ? 1 : 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Create an array with 70% 1 and 30% 0s. Then random sort it. Then start picking numbers from the beginning of the array to the end :)

```
$num_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) $num_array[$i] = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) $num_array[$i] = 1;
shuffle($num_array);
```

**Pros:**
 You'll get exactly 30% 0 and 70% 1 for any such array.

**Cons:** Might take longer computation time than a `rand()` only solution to create the initial array.

Comment: You are the fox, and thanks for the cleaver idea. If the memory is not the concern, then its a nice one with 100% perfection.

Comment: well I wouldn't bother with memory either :) Using some modular arithmetic, I would convert every request % 100 (say the initial array has size 100). And when I reach to the end once I would shuffle the array again :)

Answer (score 2):

Generate a new random value between 1 and 100. If the value falls below 30, then use `0`, and `1` otherwise:

```
$probability = rand(1, 100);
if ($probability < 30) {
    echo 0;
} else {
    echo 1;
}
```

To test this theory, consider the following loop:

```
$arr = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 10000; $i++) { 
    $rand = rand(0, 1);
    $probability = rand(1, 100);
    if ($probability < 30) {
        $arr[] = 0;
    } else {
        $arr[] = 1;
    }
}

$c = array_count_values($arr);

echo "0 = " . $c['0'] / 10000 * 100;
echo "1 = " . $c['1'] / 10000 * 100;
```

Output:

```
0 = 29.33
1 = 70.67
```

Comment: why calculate `$rand` in first step? just a computation waste, isn't it?

Comment: @Stoic: Oops, I didn't realize it was still there when I posted the answer. Thanks for notifying!

Answer (score 0):

I searched for an answer to my question and this was the topic I found.
But it didn't answered my question, so I had to figure it out myself, and I did :).

I figured out that maybe this will help someone else as well.
It's regarding what you asked, but for more usage.

Basically, I use it as a "power" calculator for a random generated item (let's say a weapon). The item has a "min power" and a "max power" value in the db. And I wanted to have 80% chances to have the "power" value closer to the lower 80% of the max possible power for the item, and 20% for the highest 20% possible max power (that are stored in the db).

So, to do this I did the following:

```
$min = 1; // this value is normally taken from the db
$max = 30; // this value is normally taken from the db

$total_possibilities = ($max - $min) + 1;

$rand = random_int(1, 100);

if ($rand <= 80) {    // 80% chances
    $new_max = $max - ($total_possibilities * 0.20); // remove 20% from the max value, so you can get a number only from the lowest 80%
    $new_rand = random_int($min, $new_max);
} elseif ($rand <= 100) {    // 20% chances
    $new_min = $min + ($total_possibilities * 0.80); // add 80% for the min value, so you can get a number only from the highest 20%
    $new_rand = random_int($new_min, $max);
}

echo $new_rand; // this will be the final item power
```

The only problem you can have, is if the initial `$min` and `$max` variables are the same (or obviously, if the `$max` is bigger than the `$min`). This will throw an error since the random works like this `($min, $max)`, not the other way around.

This code can be very easily changed to have more percentages for different purposes, instead of 80% and 20% to put 40%, 40% and 20% (or whatever you need). I think the code is pretty much easy to read and understand.

Sorry if this is not helpful, but I hope it is :).
It can't do any harm either way ;).